# bash.bashrc damaged..ubuntu log in loop and no interactive programs working from terminal

Tags: bash, display, log, bashrc

I have accidentally deleted the content of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and now I cannot log in as it gives me a loop and I cannot run any interactive programs from the terminal. When I try, I get this error:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment when trying to run gedit
GTK: cannot open display when trying to run google chrome
cannot connect to X server when trying to run rstudio
```

However, I can run non interactive programs (e.g R and python) from the terminal.

What do I need to add in `bash.bashrc` to get to see X11 or programs that use `DISPLAY`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of the file you changed. Was it `/etc/bash.bashrc` or are you referring to your own `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: Try to create a new `bash.bashrc` file. My file at Ubuntu-MATE 16.04 contains this: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17236054/ so maybe if you copy paste them it will fix the problem.